# -Wint-in-bool-context warning issue in some compilers

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I am a getting warning:
warning: '<<' in boolean context, did you mean '<' ? [-Wint-in-bool-context]
for the code similar to the following:

```
int a=7,b=3;
int index=((a<<1)||b)&&5;
```

Comment: Doing a logical operation with a constant integer (like `&& 5`) makes no sense. Integer constants are *always* true (if non-zero) or *always* false (if zero). The code you show would only make sense if using the bitwise OR and AND operations `|` and `&`. (assuming both `a` and `b` are really initialized).

Comment: What's this expression even supposed to mean? Did you mean to use _bitwise_ OR/AND?

Comment: Expression is fine. There are logical operators || and && used with integers to reproduce this warning. But some compilers do not reproduce this because of updates or warning filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the rationale behind such warnings:

C did get a boolean type `_Bool`/`bool` as per C99, but no changes were done to the behavior of the various logical operators of the language. That is:

- Equality operators `==`/`!=`
- Relational operators `<`,`<=`,`>`,`>=`
- Logical AND `&&`
- Logical OR `||`
- Logical negation `!`.

Despite C having a boolean type, all of these operators return type `int` with value `1` or `0`. Unlike C++ where all of these operators actually return type `bool` with value `true`/`false`. This is a known flaw of C.

It's common good practice however to treat such expressions as if they were boolean. Coding guidelines like MISRA C encourage the use of a fictional type "essentially boolean", meaning any expression that could be treated as `_Bool`. The reason for this is that it makes code more self-documenting and also makes it harder to create various typo-related bugs.

For example `if(str)` could mean check for `NULL`, or it could mean check for null termination but oops we forgot to dereference. Same thing with `if(*str)`. Whereas if we only pass the result of a logical operator to `if`, the code becomes much clearer and it becomes harders to write bugs: `if(str != NULL)` could only mean check for NULL and `if(*str != '\0')` could only mean check for null termination.

In your case, the `||` operator only cares if the operands are zero or non-zero ("essentially boolean"). In case `a` is non-zero then `a<<1` will not change that. In case `a` is zero, then `a<<1` is zero as well. Since the result is passed on to a logical operator, "in a boolean context", the shift is pointless - hence the warning. But of course `a<<1` might take all kinds of other values in another context such as for example `if(a<<1 & mask)`.

It would be reasonable to strongly suspect that you actually meant to write `a<1` instead. Because that would yield either 0 or 1, where `<` is also a logical operator like `||`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. We should avoid integers using with logical operators (eg. ||,&&). Using integers with bitwise operators (eg. <<,&,|,etc.) is fine.

Sometimes we don't get this problem while running on compilers because of low priority warning filters. In complex and warning sensitive compilers it comes up.

Thanks